# Starting Datalab from Cloud Shell

Tags: docker, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-datalab, google-cloud-shell

The [Datalab documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/) shows how to run datalab on:

- your own machine or,
- on Google Cloud Platform.

Unfortunately if you are restricted to a Windows 7/8 machine without the required [Docker support](https://www.docker.com/products/docker#/windows), I don't think you have easy* options to deploy datalab.

What is the recommended way to deploy Datalab, since the datalab deployer is now deprecated?

*You could of course run Linux in Virtualbox and deploy everything from there, but it's not really easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two quick comments:

1. There are issues with using Cloud Dev Shell - one mentioned above
       plus problems with the communication protocol between the notebook
       server and the kernel and a few others. So we decided against
       documenting this as an alternative to Docker installation at this point.
2. There is a better alternative now that is documented here: 
       https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-gce-frontend.
       It requires the ability to create an SSH tunnel from your client
       (Mac/Windows etc) to the GCE VM running Datalab but should otherwise free you from the Docker installation requirement.

Thanks.

Dinesh

(Cloud Datalab Product Manager)

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed a great new alternative!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have come up with is using [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/) in combination with [container engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/quickstart).

Below, you can find the commands to paste in Cloud Shell, this will return the IP address of the service running datalab:

```
gcloud container clusters create datalab-cluster --machine-type n1-standard-4 --num-nodes 1 --zone europe-west1-d --scopes cloud-platform
kubectl run datalab --image=gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local --port=80
kubectl expose deployment datalab --type="LoadBalancer"
kubectl get service datalab
```

To stop/delete datalab you run this command in Cloud Shell:

`gcloud container clusters delete datalab-cluster`

**Note1:** If you delete the datalab service, you will also lose your data, so keep in mind to copy your data-folder to Google Cloud Storage.

**Note2:** When I try to use the Sign in button in the upper right corner in Datalab, this always fails (redirects to localhost). You can also login using the gcloud commands in Datalab:

- run: `!echo Y |gcloud auth login --no-launch-browser`
- go to the url that was returned in the previous step, click on login and copy the returned code
- run: `!echo <code>|!echo Y |gcloud auth login --no-launch-browser` with `<code>`, the code obtained in the previous step

**Edit:**
As mentioned by @Dinesh (PM Datalab), there is a [new alternative](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-gce-frontend) available now that works better than this method and doesn't require Docker on your machine.